# how to draw a Bitmap on the Top Right of the Canvas

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-canvas, rect

I am trying to draw a bitmap on `top right hand corner` of the `Canvas`

So far I have done the following:

```
//100x40 dimensions for the bitmap
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.backbutton);

Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
Rect bitmapRect = new Rect(0, 0, canvasWidth -200,50);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source, bitmapRect, paint);
```

The problem is that when I run the app, the bitmap doesn't appear on the screen.
Full code:

```
public class MyView extends View {
Rect bitmapRect;
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.backbutton);

    Rect source = new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmapRect = new Rect(0,0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source, bitmapRect, new Paint());

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y =   (int)event.getY();
    if(null != bitmapRect && bitmapRect.contains(x,y)){
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "this works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

Can someone help me here please?

Comment: put null where you have the paint in draw bitmap

Comment: I tried that but it only flipped the image but doesnt cover the top right corner

Comment: for your bitmapRect where it says canvasWidth - 200, use the original bitmap that you put into the canvas's width - whatever, try that

Comment: a bitmap being flipped is the result of a negative number

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the `use the original bitmap that you put into the canvas's width - whatever, try that`

Comment: put up the rest of your code

Comment: check out my answer, i didnt know you were using a View, i thought it was just a regular canvas when your code wasnt up, that is how you do it extending a view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in MyView right under Rect bitmapRect; make the variables

```
public int width;
public int height;
```

then in your MyView class put this method in there

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
width = w;
height = h;
}
```

now you have the width and height of the canvas that you are using
then in your onDraw() method make the bitmapRect like this

```
bitmapRect = new Rect(width -200,0, width, 50);
```

i think the problem is that how you had it you had a negative number in your rect and it was inverting the bitmap, when you use a draw command with Rects, one is the source of what your going to draw and one is the destination of where its going to be drawn

Comment: Still the same problem =( its covering the the area from top left but doesnt cover the top right

Comment: see i just changed the bitmapRect

Comment: like that, my bad again

Comment: Not sure why it is happening. I am wondering whether there is another way to draw the bitmap at x,y location and test bounds for motionevent

Comment: i had the rect wrong how i had it(width-200,0,200,50) was wrong how i just put it up is correct, it should be somewhat what your looking for

Comment: you just have to tweak it out to your specifications

Comment: no problem, glad to be of assistance, sorry about the confusion

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out with a tricky problem! have a great day