# Android Bitmap Matrix postScale method ruins bitmap quality

Tags: android, bitmap, scale, flip

I am trying to flip an image view horizontally after putting a Sobel Filter on it. The filter converts the image in black and white and then then I do this to flip the image horizontally.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.preScale( - 1, 1 );
Bitmap resizedBitmap =
                        Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false );
```

What happens is really weird. My image flips correctly but the dark spots get whiter. I have attached two images for comparison.[image]

Comment: try Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, -bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), false ); without the matrix, a negative number should flip the bitmap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777340/how-to-draw-a-bitmap-on-the-top-right-of-the-canvas/18777757#18777757